# Выражение "наше всё"

Tags: лексика

Объясните, пожалуйста, что значит выражение **"наше всё"** ?

Например: *"Толстой -- наше всё"*.

Откуда оно пошло? Не от увлечения ли идеями Льва Толстого (т.н. "толстовцев" в начале ХХ века)? Если, конечно, вообще возможно на сегодняшний день понять происхождение этого выражения.

Но его происхождение для меня второстепенно, интереснее точное значение этих слов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчет Толстого - не знаю, А вообще выражение получило широкую известность в связи с высказыванием Аполлона Григорьева о Пушкине.

Поскольку интересует именно значение, то дальнейшие рассуждения на тему классиков опускаю. Выражение приобрело идиоматический характер и означает высшую оценку деятельности кого-либо в конкретной области или таланта, значимости. "Путин - наше всё". 
Встречается употребление "Наше все" без имени собственного как обозначение самого Пушкина.